# How to prevent duplicate primary key in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to save form record and I take entities from client side but every time it takes `PersonalId = 0` and this will be duplicate primary key error.

How can I fix that?

```
public ActionResult SavePersonal(PersonalViewModel model)
{
    try 
    {
        StorageSystemEntities1 db = new StorageSystemEntities1();

        Personal personal = new Personal();
        personal.PName = model.PName;
        personal.PLastname = model.PLastname;
        personal.PStatus = model.PStatus;
        personal.ShopId = model.ShopId;
        personal.PPassword = model.PPassword;
        personal.GenderID = model.GenderID;
        personal.DOB = model.DOB;
        personal.Email = model.Email;
        personal.JobStartDate = model.JobStartDate;
        personal.PAuthorisation = model.PAuthorisation;
        personal.Phone = model.Phone;

        db.Personal.Add(personal);
        db.SaveChanges();

        int latestPersonalId = personal.PersonalID;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("_AddPersonal");
}
```

Comment: You use an IDENTITY column on the database table, and you create a Primary Key constraint on the same column

Comment: ^^^^ With Identity Seed and Increment. If you're using Entity Framework, you'll need to put `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` as an attribute on the `PersonalID` property

Comment: in database i have PersonalID and i want to increase it every save recort but it takes always 0

Comment: Did you use Sql Server? If yes set the IDENTITY property to true, and do not forget to make it your primary key for the table

Comment: i set identity true but its not work and program said set it "off" :)

Answer (score 0):

Few ways to pass this through, i.e.:

- generate unique id in your app (i.e. guid)
- same thing but in your db engine (i.e. sql procedure)
- use sql identity as mentioned in the previous answer, hence nothing should be done in your app
- hope one of the above helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` in your `Personal` class.

Example:

```
public class Personal {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonalId {get;set;}
    public string PName {get;set;}
    public string PLastname {get;set;}
    public string PStatus {get;set;}
    public int ShopId {get;set;}
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string PPassword {get;set;}
    public string GenderID {get;set;}
    public DateTime? DOB  {get;set;}
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public DateTime? JobStartDate  {get;set;}
    public string PAuthorisation {get;set;}
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone {get;set;}
}
```